# Alternative to ownCloud that supports encryption

Tags: gratis, file-management, php, encryption

I'm looking for an alternative to [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/) that meets these requirements,

- PHP based
- Gratis (or at least free for personal use)
- Encrypts files all the time (some software encrypts files, but to access them you have to decrypt them on the server's disk, that's kind of useless right?)
- Simple to install (meaning I don't have to install extra packages on the actual operating system, for instance Pydio for encryption needs to have ENCFS on the server to encrypt files - I'm on shared hosting so that is not something I can do. Also, [seafile](http://manual.seafile.com/deploy/using_mysql.html) is not an alternative either as it requires I run an install script through a shell, something I don't have access to either)

Some features that are not requirements but wanted are,

- Has apps for either/both iPhone & Android
- Has sync software for either/both Windows & OS X
- Open Source

**Note**: ownCloud includes encrypted storage as an option, I'm wondering if there is anything else that supports encryption as well.

Comment: So you want to upload the files unencrypted, and the Web app should encrypt them? And which features should the Web interface have? Is a list of file links sufficient, without any categories/tags/filters? And for unencrypting: if it’s not an Android/iOS app, for which operating system (or browser, in case of an add-on) do you need this?

Comment: 1) @unor I really don't care (well, I do, but don't know if any  will meet the third requirement so I don't want to be too choosy if you know what I mean).

Comment: 2) Yes,  I would like the web interface too (or for the interface to work with server software that will) take the encrypted files put it in the memory (or wherever) and then encrypt the files. Basically, I want to be able to go to any computer with a browser, load the web app, and upload files. I do not want at any time though to have the files unencrypted on the actual disk of the server, what it can do is have the files unencrypted in its memory for a brief period of time while it's encrypted it to the disk.